# img tag not allowing overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

So i'm trying to use an img tag to make a background img in html/css but my img tag will not allow things to overlap it and when I try to use a div class element it does not stretch to edge of page even with width at 100%. here is my css and html.

```
 .backgroundImage {
background: url(/images/mainBackground.jpeg) top no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
} 

.img{
z-index:0;
}

.img-responsive{
 height:auto; 
 width:100%
}
```

These are the two ways I've tried:

```
<img src="../images/mainBackground.jpeg" class="shadow-offset   img-responsive"/> 

<div class="backgroundImage">
```

The div ending after everything but my footer

I have containers but neither of these are inside any containers either because they start at the top of the page before I use containers at all.

Answer (score 1):

wrap all of your html in a `<html>` tag, then use the following css:

```
html {
   background-image: url("image/url.png");
}
```

Comment: No luck. Image completely dissapears.@TheOneWhoMade

Comment: yes. Same as my other used in my css, which works fine.

Comment: still no luck. I tried in js fiddle. background worked until I pulled in bootstrap dependencies.. @TheOneWhoMade

Comment: you may have to use your other html, then use it as a template and put your content where the other content was. @ebraun99

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163883/discussion-between-theonewhomade-and-ebraun99).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume all you're trying to do is add a background image to your div - your explanation is a little unclear. The following is all you'll need:

```
// html
<div class="backgroundImage">...</div>

// css
.backgroundImage {
  background-image: url('/images/mainBackground.jpeg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

`div` elements are display:block by default, which means it should be 100% width. Unless there's something in your markup you're not showing us, there's no need to add `width: 100%`. Also, the div will also automatically change height based on its content. In this case, using `background-size:cover` will allow the background image to resize and fill the div regardless of size.

Unless... you're floating things inside the div. Then you're going to need a clear, like this:

```
// html
<div class="backgroundImage clear">...</div>

// css
.clear::after {
   content: '';
   display: table;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: cover is not what I want. I want something that goes to the width of the screen and adjusts depending on screen size. img tag is not allowing overlap but giving me correct size and div is not wide enough based on my current css and html. Does that make sense?